# Solr booster by date range relevance

Tags: c#, solr

I am searching by date range by relevance.
Using this URL :

```
(((publicationdate:[1919-12-31T00:00:00.000Z TO 1977-12-31T23:59:59.999Z])^1000)     OR((publicationdate:[1978-01-01T00:00:00.000Z TO 2014-12-31T23:59:59.999Z]))^1)
```

How to boost particular date range, i used ^1000 but its not working, Any other idea or suggestion?

For example. I searched from 1920-2014, so i want for year 1920-1977 records comes first and for year 1977-2014 records comes in last.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have the boost in your boost query instead (the `bq` parameter). Add the `publicationdate` (1920 - 1977) query there, and you should see the boost applied. In the first case the second part of the OR statement will be the complete set of documents, and their scoring won't change (I'm guessing - but you can confirm with debugQuery).